# Knockout.js text binding in child node

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I'm quite new to knockout.js and I couldn't find an answer for this question.

I'm trying to create something like

```
<td>DEMO<span>DEMO2</span></td>
```

But I'm not sure how to do it with knockout.js. I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
<td data-bind="text: type"><span data-bind="text: type2"></span></td>
```

It seems `text:type` is overriding the `span` and it doesn't even appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you cannot have your `text` binding on the `td` because it completly overrides the content of your `td`

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html):

> Knockout sets the element’s content to a text node with your parameter value. Any previous content will be overwritten.

Solutions:

Use an extra `span`:

```
<td><span data-bind="text: type"></span><span data-bind="text: type2"></span></td>
```

Use the contenerless syntax of KO:

```
<td><!-- ko text: type --><!-- /ko --><span data-bind="text: type2"></span></td>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zc61gy77/).

Comment: Thanks! The containerless solution seems to be the way to go for it!